# How to apply top level namespace using kubernetes go client

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

Using kubectl we can specify which namespace should we install the resources in, example ->
kubectl apply -f abc.yaml -n mynamespace

this would ensure all my resources are creates in 'mynamespace'.

How do I achieve this using the Kubernetes Go client. I am looking for ways which DO NOT involve changing each and every helm/yaml and adding namespaces explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see how kubectl does it here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/fe3772890f650f9bcf020b43dc5a51fab0fa17f4/staging/src/k8s.io/cli-runtime/pkg/resource/helper.go#L240-L248

```
func (m *Helper) createResource(c RESTClient, resource, namespace string, obj runtime.Object, options *metav1.CreateOptions) (runtime.Object, error) {
    return c.Post().
        NamespaceIfScoped(namespace, m.NamespaceScoped).
        Resource(resource).
        VersionedParams(options, metav1.ParameterCodec).
        Body(obj).
        Do(context.TODO()).
        Get()
}
```

You can use use [`NamespaceIfScoped`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/af4295f5013b55c45b05f1e7850f7fa9c4dbfdb4/rest/request.go#L306-L312) to override the namespace at the request level.

Answer (score 0):

Most functions for creating resources in the Kubernetes go client accept the namespace for an argument.

You can also set a different default namespace in your kubeconfig context:

```
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: example
    namespace: mynamespace
    user: example
  name: example
```

More details can be found here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/

Then when you import your kubeconfig, all your resources should be created in that namespace. Look at this example on how to import your kubeconfig:

[main.go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/a6ca2f510ccabe50c7c24e54a0740d0b8decdfc3/examples/out-of-cluster-client-configuration/main.go)